# click events on flags doesn't work in Highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi everyone I need to convert some code from old highstock lib to new one, but I can't make the click event work on flags. I am adding example of what happens. It always fires first series events, but I need to get flag event and use its data later on. also, this data will be later on added dynamically. 
PS. It needs to work without jQuery. 
Thank you

```js
var DD = [
 {x: 1438639200000},
 {x: 1438719200000}
];


var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
 rangeSelector: {
  selected: 0
 },
 series: [{
  name: 'ADBE',
  data: ADBE,
  point:{
   events: {
    click: function () {
     alert('first Series');
    }
   }
  }
 },{     
  name: 'Flags',
  type: 'flags',
  data: DD,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  point: {
   events: {
    click: function () {
     alert('second Series');
    }
   }
  },
  zIndex: 500
 }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/three-series-1000-points.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is a bug which appeared in highstock 5.0.12 - see the github ticket https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6764 It should be fixed in the next release. If you need flags events you should stick to 5.0.11 version for now.

Comment: @morganfree thank you for this. I just not sure if the 5.0.11 or even earlier had an issue with combining multiple axes with using crosshair. it uses to stuck the pointer on some axis while hovering on other. I will check 5.0.11 out thanks again